# Integral of Gromov product

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Consider a geodesic, hyperbolic metric space $(X,d)$. For $x,y \in X$, consider $D(x,y)$ the infimum, over all $1$-Lipschitz paths $p:[a,b] \rightarrow X$ from $x$ to $y$, of the integral $\int_a^b e^{-(x|y)_{p(t)}}dt$, where $(x|y)_{p(t)}$ is the Gromov product.

Is the function $D(x,y)$ metrically proper ? More precisely, does there exist constants $A,B > 0$ such that $D(x,y) \geq Ad(x,y)-B$ ? Has this quantity already been studied ?

Comment: Do you want $|b - a| = d(x,y)$ ?

Comment: No, I do not impose any restrictions on $b-a$.

Comment: So you do not need the 1-Lipschitz condition. Just Lipschitz is enough. Or something I am missing here?

Comment: If you parametrize a geodesic from $x$ to $y$ by some interval $[a,b]$ (even Lipschitz), the integral equals $b-a$. So the infimum is zero if you do not restrict to $1$-Lipschitz paths.

Comment: ah, ok I understand